# SignalR Self Hosted application in 2020

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, signalr

I started using SignalR in console/desktop application from its first release years ago and then switched to other duties. Now it seems that many things changed, and it is not possible anymore to create a simple console chat application hosting a SignalR hub.

Is my understanding right? Do I have to install ASP.net extensions in Visual Studio to access SignalR API? And, does this mean that I need IIS? Am I obliged to use javascript on client side? I'd like to develop a WPF client.

Could someone please clarify my point of view on this topic?
Thank you

Comment: no, no, no, no and maybe

Comment: You should only know, that there is `ASP.net SignalR` and `ASP.net SignalR Core` which are incompatible.

Comment: SignalR is a part of ASP.net framework but [it can be hosted in the console application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-3.1) (as any ASP.net) using the Kestrel. Here is [the start guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?tabs=visual-studio&view=aspnetcore-3.1). You will need the ASP.net VS extension to get project templates. However the same code can be written "by hands"

Comment: Why would you *host* SignalR in a WPF applictation instead of an ASP.NET Core app (using IIS or not)? You can certainly *consume* it from a WPF application anyway.

Comment: @mm8 I never told that I'd like to host SignalR  in a WPF. I told that I need a _client_ in WPF ...

Comment: All those changes might not be applicable to your case. Name the actual issue and the troubleshooting you have done so far.

Comment: @rPulvi: You need to know whether to connect to a classic ASP.NET SignalR host or an ASP.NET Core one. There are client APIs for both. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Am I obliged to use javascript on client side?

Certainly not. [Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR/) is the .NET client API for the classic ASP.NET SignalR and [Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client/) is the client API for the new and improved ASP.NET Core SignalR. You can download and install them both from NuGet.

ASP.NET Core SignalR isn't compatible with clients or servers for ASP.NET SignalR so you need to know what version is running on the host that you are connecting to.

[Differences between ASP.NET SignalR and ASP.NET Core SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/version-differences?view=aspnetcore-3.1)